# Trouble with GWT/GXT internationalisation

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, constants, gxt

I'm trying to add _ro.properties files to my Sencha GXT application.

The problem is that the app completely ignores my locale and uses the default .properties file.

The files are added in the same package ("client.constants") as follows:

LoginWindowConstants.java:

```
package com.itsix.logbook.client.constants;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface LoginWindowConstants extends Constants {
@DefaultStringValue("Login to Amsterdam Arena logbook")
String title();

@DefaultStringValue("Login")
String loginButtonLabel();

@DefaultStringValue("Username")
String userNameFieldLabel();

@DefaultStringValue("Password")
String passwordFieldLabel();

    @DefaultStringValue("Forgotten password")
    String forgottenPasswordButtonLabel();
}
```

LoginWindowConstants_ro.properties:

```
$PP_OFF
title=Login to Amsterdam Arena Logbook - RO Properties
loginButtonLabel=Login
userNameFieldLabel=Username
passwordFieldLabel=Password
forgottenPasswordButtonLabel=Forgotten Password
```

Added the following to the .xml file

```
      <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
      <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>

  <!--  supported locale settings -->
  <extend-property name="locale" values="ro" />
```

I'm hoping someone with a bit more experience can let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just making the locale available

It should work by adding a parameter to the url

> xyz.com?locale=ro

To set Russian as the default you should use [(as described in the GWT docs)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale):

```
 <!-- SETS AS THE DEFAULT -->
 <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="ro"/>
```

Comment: U can use this tag in jsp.As soon as u load it will take locale which is sepecified in meta tag.<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=ro">

Comment: Yeah I use gwt:property in a jsp too -- <meta name="gwt:property" content="<%=locale%>"> and figure out what to set it from request.getHeader("Accept-language") ... but still set the default in case no locales match the Accept-language header